# Download Google Drive csv file via Javascript with Google Auth popup providing token?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I want to have some local javascript code hit the google drive api and download a csv of a Google sheet for a simple automation tool.

I want a quick OAuth popup to ask the user to accept and then fire off the request and get the csv. It's done here when you click "try" and populate the file id (a google sheet) and the mime type (a simple csv):

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/export

In their demo it opens a popup that lets the user login or just grant whatever is needed then return the CSV data so I can do whatever I need on it. However, their code doesn't show how to do make the popup/redirect happen and get the token to make the call.

I don't want to have to make an APP, generate private keys, or go through setting up a whole bunch of api shenanigans. This is so it's simple for the user.

Whatever they're doing on this page is making this happen automatically - how can I reproduce this? I've attached a screenshot showing what I see when I click "execute".[image: excecuting on google]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `have some local javascript code hit the google drive api and download a csv of a Google sheet for a simple automation tool`. Can I ask you about the details of your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: If you want access to private user data you are going to have to create an app with keys and get the app verified